# All results are undefined from access database

Tags: javascript, sql, ms-access

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong and it's driving me nuts.  Here's some javascript code that is querying an access database.  All of the RS.fields[i] are undefined, but then there are the correct numbers of rows returned.  Any idea what is causing this?

```
adOpenForwardOnly = 0;
adLockReadOnly = 1;
adCmdText = 1;
var data = new Array();
var myConnect = 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\\asdf.mdb'; 

var ConnectObj = new ActiveXObject('ADODB.Connection');
var RS = new ActiveXObject('ADODB.Recordset');
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM TTT WHERE XXX = "'+xxx+'" AND YYY = "'+yyy+'" AND ZZZ = '+zzz+' AND AAA =  "'+aaa+'" AND BBB = #'+bbb+'# ';
//alert(sql);
ConnectObj.Open(myConnect);
RS.Open(sql, ConnectObj);

RS.MoveFirst();
while(!RS.eof){
    data.push( new FFFRow( 
                    'a', 
                    parseFloat(RS.fields[1]),
                    new String(RS.fields[8]), 
                    GetDateFromString(RS.fields[9]), 
                    GetDateFromString(RS.fields[10]),
                    GetDateFromString(RS.fields[4]), 
                    GetDateFromString(RS.fields[12]), 
                    parseFloat(RS.fields[13]), 
                    parseFloat(RS.fields[14]), 
                    new String(RS.fields[15]), 
                    parseFloat(RS.fields[16]), 
                    parseFloat(RS.fields[17]),
                    parseFloat(RS.fields[18]), 
                    parseFloat(RS.fields[19]), 
                    '', 
                    '', 
                    parseFloat(RS.fields[0]), 
                    new String(RS.fields[3]), 
                    new String(RS.fields[2])
                )
            );

    RS.MoveNext();
}
```

Comment: Grab your SQL statement and paste it into a new Query in MS Access directly - see what you get.

Comment: I've been doing this and the query works fine in access.  it's really weird because I'm getting the correct number of rows, but everything is turning up undefined

Comment: output RS.fields[1].name, see if you get the column name. Or try: set RS = ConnectObj.Execute(sql); instead of RS.open.

Comment: @Diodeus, still all undefined.  This is so weird! :(

Comment: The while loop stops after the correct number of rows have been added to "data" so I'm assuming EOF is being set properly at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RS.Fields.Item(1)
```

Note, Fields is cap, Item is cap and it is a function call not array reference.

Comment: Yeah, after some painstaking work, I arrived at this conclusion.  Gosh, took me so long to find something so insignificant. :(  Thanks :)